# GAE not working for send mail using Send Grid using java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, email, sendgrid

I'm trying to send a mail using SendGrid by deploying my code to GAE. Following is my code.

```
private static final String SMTP_HOST_NAME = "smtp.sendgrid.net";
    private static final String SMTP_AUTH_USER = "*******";
    private static final String SMTP_AUTH_PWD = "*******";
    private static final int SMTP_PORT = 2525;

    public void sendCustomer(String userName, String toEmail, int custId) {

        try {
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

            Authenticator auth = new SMTPAuthenticator();
            Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, auth);
            Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport();


            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);

            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("alternative");

            // Sets up the contents of the email message
            BodyPart part1 = new MimeBodyPart();

            part1.setText("Hello "
                    + userName
                    + "\n\n\n\n"
                    + "Welcome to NotionViz. You have been registered successfully in NotionViz.");

            multipart.addBodyPart(part1);
            message.setText("UTF-8", "html");
            message.setContent(multipart);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(SMTP_AUTH_USER));
            message.setSubject("Customer Registration");
            InternetAddress internetAddress = null;

            try {
                internetAddress = new InternetAddress(toEmail);
                internetAddress.validate();

            } catch (Exception e) {

                System.out.println("Not a valid email address");

            }
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, internetAddress);

            InternetAddress address = new InternetAddress("cloud.spaninfotech@gmail.com");

            message.setFrom(address);

            // Sends the email
            transport.connect(SMTP_HOST_NAME, SMTP_PORT, SMTP_AUTH_USER,
                    SMTP_AUTH_PWD);
            transport.sendMessage(message,
                    message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
            transport.sendMessage(message,
                    message.getFrom());
            transport.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }

    // Authenticates to SendGrid
    class SMTPAuthenticator extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
        @Override
        public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            String username = SMTP_AUTH_USER;
            String password = SMTP_AUTH_PWD;
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
        }
    }
```

This program is working fine and sending mail in local. But if i deploy to GAE and check, I'm not getting an email. Please let me know why GAE restricting third party mail sending.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the port that you're using. You can hit SendGrid over port 587, 25 or 2525 for plain/TLS connections (465 if you were going to be using SSL).

SendGrid suggests port 587 to avoid rate limits set by some hosting companies so I would give that a shot.

Answer (score 0):

On GAE sockets are a subject to a series of restrictions (see Sockets API [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/sockets/)). Authenticated SMTP is allowed on submission port 587, so you can use it as already suggested by LaCroixed.